# Why does Tensorflow show memory available less than GPU specs?

Tags: tensorflow, nvidia

This command is giving GPU with 4614 MB Memory.

But the RTX2060 has 6GB Memory.  Why is it showing only just over 4GB?

```
>>> tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()
True
>>> tf.test.is_gpu_available(cuda_only=False,min_cuda_compute_capability=None)
2019-10-29 17:02:40.062465: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2019-10-29 17:02:40.072455: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2019-10-29 17:02:40.105489: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce RTX 2060 major: 7 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.2
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
2019-10-29 17:02:40.111138: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dlopen_checker_stub.cc:25] GPU libraries are statically linked, skip dlopen check.
2019-10-29 17:02:40.117217: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1763] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-10-29 17:02:44.865862: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1181] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-10-29 17:02:44.870341: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1187]      0
2019-10-29 17:02:44.872351: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1200] 0:   N
2019-10-29 17:02:44.876727: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1326] Created TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0 with 4614 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2060, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorflow reports the memory it's able to use on the device. So if you have anything else using some GPU memory, the memory reported by TensorFlow will be lower than the total available memory.

Also, some OS only allows a certain fraction of the memory to be used by applications to ensure it will still be able to use the device (cf this issue on TensorFlow's GitHub: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22623)

Comment: Thank you. Is there  a way I can use it to use more than this? I think 2GB is more and is almost  30% wasted...

Comment: You can try to have as few programs running in parallel as possible. On Linux, the tool `nvidia-smi` allows you to get information on all the software currently using some GPU memory, there might be an equivalent on Windows to know more about that. Also, Windows is stashing some of the memory for its own use, so if you really need to maximize available memory, you can try to use Linux (propaganda inside :D).